# Which application responds to a keybind (desktop)

Tags: linux, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

Here is my interesting situation. I have a Linux Mint installation (Gnome), over which I installed Compiz Fusion because that is how I used to do things in the past. At some point Gnome broke, didn't have time to investigate so I put xfce on top. Total mambo jumbo, but I don't have time now to fix it properly. I now want to rebind `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L`, but I don't even know which app picks it up.

My question is: what debugging tool should I use to figure out which application receives my keybind? Is there a central dispatcher in Linux? Is there at least a log I can read? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can run `grep '&lt;Primary&gt;&lt;Alt&gt;l' ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` to see what is using it. All keyboard shortcuts for Xfce are stored in that file. They correspond to the shortcuts in Keyboard > Application Shortcuts and in Window Manager > Keyboard. Shortcuts can also be changed in Settings Editor > xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.